# Conectar via odbc 64 bits em banco Sybase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nhibernate, sybase

Estou tentando conectar em um banco de dados via Odbc, e utilizo o driver System.Data.Odbc. Em odbc 32-bits funciona já, em odbc 64-bits não.

```
 IDictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            properties.Add("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver");
            properties.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseASA10Dialect");
            properties.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle");
            properties.Add("hibernate.connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
            properties.Add("connection.connection_string", "DSN=CONNECTION");
            properties.Add("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none");

            InPlaceConfigurationSource source = new InPlaceConfigurationSource();

            source.Add(typeof(ActiveRecordBase), properties);
            tipos = GetAllClasses().GetTypes();
            ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source, tipos);
            ISessionFactoryHolder holder = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder();
            _sessionFactory = holder.GetSessionFactory(typeof(ActiveRecordBase));
```

Quando tento conectar na odbc 64-bits tenho retorno do seguinte erro:

```
ERROR [IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Comment: Você está rodando o projeto com IIS express?

Comment: Não é uma aplicação desktop, no windows.

Comment: E você configurou a conexão no ODBC 64bits?

Comment: Deixei somente configurado na ODBC 64bits, mas quando dou publish não conecta a aplicação.